# Unable to access my self hosted Virtual server(Ubuntu 20.04) which is in my house but want to access from office

Tags: virtual-machine, ubuntu-18.04, virtualhost, virtualization

I have created ubuntu server in my vmware and able to host website with in network throuhgh any device but when i access same website form my office or any other internet it shows that website never been publicshed. my concern is how to get my serve live outside from house.

Example : hosted vmware server in my home but i want to access from my office